# Calculating coordinates between 2 points using distance travelled from first point

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get geo-location coordinates of current location between points a and b, knowing only distance travelled from point a, assuming user has gone in a straight line

```
var disatnce_travelled = 375; //miles
function initialize() {
var locations = new Array(new google.maps.LatLng(40.7142700, -74.0059700),new google.maps.LatLng(43.585278, 39.720278));
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for(i in locations)
    bounds.extend(locations[i]);
var mapOptions = {
 zoom: 3,
 center: bounds.getCenter(),
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
   mapOptions);

var flightPlanCoordinates = locations;
var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
 path: flightPlanCoordinates,
 strokeColor: '#7f3f98',
 strokeOpacity: 1.0,
 strokeWeight: 2
});

flightPath.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Post the code you've written and explain what issues you're having. This isn't a question.

Comment: updated with my code so far. I want to draw where between locations[0] and locations[1] the user is, knowing disatnce_travelled

Comment: Are you assuming that the user travels in a straight line between the points?

Comment: The [google.maps.geomettry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) has an interpolate method. `Returns the LatLng which lies the given fraction of the way between the origin LatLng and the destination LatLng.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [google.maps.geomettry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) has an interpolate method. `Returns the LatLng which lies the given fraction of the way between the origin LatLng and the destination LatLng.`

However that seems to interpolate along a geodesic path. [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_interpolate.html)

One option would be to use the v3 port of [Mike Williams' epoly library](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/epoly.htm)

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>
<script src="scripts/v3_epoly.js"></script>
<script>
var distance_travelled = 375; //miles
function initialize() {
var locations = new Array(new google.maps.LatLng(40.7142700, -74.0059700),new google.maps.LatLng(43.585278, 39.720278));
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for(i in locations)
    bounds.extend(locations[i]);
var mapOptions = {
 zoom: 2,
 center: bounds.getCenter(),
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
   mapOptions);

var flightPlanCoordinates = locations;
var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
 path: flightPlanCoordinates,
 strokeColor: '#7f3f98',
 strokeOpacity: 1.0,
 strokeWeight: 2
});

flightPath.setMap(map);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: flightPath.GetPointAtDistance(distance_travelled*1609.34),
   map:map});
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_interpolateC.html)

Comment: what does 1609.34 represent?

Comment: The [number of meters in a mile](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=meters+per+mile#q=meters+per+mile)